# How to get API key for getting the email previews using Litmus?

Tags: api

How to get the API key for the authentication purposes for posting the request to get the email previews using Litmus?

Answer (score 1):

There are actually a few different Litmus Preview APIs to cater to different use cases. We're in the process of simplifying this, partly in the hope of making the experience for a new API user a little more obvious.

If you reach out to hello@litmus.com we'll direct you to the appropriate API version and how to obtain your key.